# How to deploy scheduled classes through ant?

Tags: migration, ant

Is there any attribute that i can specify in build.xml to deploy scheduled classes through ant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a Scheduled Job which has code referenced you are deploying, it will fail with that error.

You need to remove the scheduled jobs (DELETE) from the Scheduled Jobs.
To confim / remove the scheduled jobs:
Setup -> Monitoring -> Scheduled Jobs

Also you need to remove the Batch Jobs if any are queued or in progress. 
Setup -> Monitoring -> Batch Jobs
 .Direct from salesfroce forums. Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: This will be eased once Winter '15 is out: http://docs.releasenotes.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_deploy_with_jobs.htm

Comment: This feature is already available in 32.0 in sandboxes.